# Proper way to reuse delegate events in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to see if I can use delegate events and reuse them so that I do not have to make multiple click events. Right now I have the following...

```
namespace EventsWPF
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void MyEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e); 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btn1.Click += MyEvent;
        btn2.Click += MyEvent;
    }


}
```

}

Is this the correct way to do it? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? I know you can use Lambda expressions as an event handler. But if I have multiple events I don't want to create multiple Lamda expressions for each handler when I can just reuse a delegate.

Comment: Does that compile?  If not what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if two buttons should have the same exact logic run; then attaching the same handler is *perfectly fine*. You won't be able to do it by attaching a `delegate` type though; you'll need an actual method (as described by @hoodaticus).

**If this is in WPF:**

Usually however, two buttons don't do the same thing and you can't get away with this. Far more commonly, two buttons do the same thing but with different arguments. Unfortunately, a WinForms style approach will be very painful here (you can check against `sender` but.... ewww).

In that case (actually, in all cases) you really want to take advantage of the MVVM pattern and set up commands for your buttons (not click handlers). Then you can use `CommandParameter` to get the custom piece of data into the handler.

Comment: I agree with all of this answer.  If a lambda is to be reused in this context it should be done via an ICommand wrapper.  However, I'm not sure this question is actually about WPF, it looks like WPF was just an example.

Comment: @hoodaticus Fair enough; my first paragraph stands apart from a WPF specific context though

Comment: Okay this makes sense. But aren't Lambda functions delegates? I guess the way I was thinking about this is that Lambda functions are delegates which are methods. So technically since delegates are methods I should be able to use them as an event. Is this the wrong way of thinking about this?

Comment: @PandaLuna Yes... but you have to be careful with the term "delegate". Using the `delegate` keyword creates a new type, one that describes a particular method signature. When we pass around methods we refer to them as "delegates" (and aren't wrong) but the way your code used it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

`MyEvent` is unnecessary here as you are not creating your own event, just subscribing to someone else's.  The `delegate` keyword declares a method signature and return type - it does not create instances or define method bodies.

Here is how you re-use a lambda expression:

```
Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> myHandler = (o, e) => 
{ 
    /* write event handler code here, you must */  
};

btn1.Click += myHandler;
btn2.Click += myHandler;
```